# Cake PHP issues on start

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have css and js inside webroot folder, but all are not loading ...

It gets an error in firebug

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/cakephp/"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/cakephp/css/common.css"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/cakephp/js/common.js"
```

My Base folder is **cakephp**. But some contents is displaying in page(http://localhost/cakephp/) with no style. Contents are coming from database.

Main Redirect links are also not working...

> The requested URL /cakephp/videos/list was not found on this server.

Only Home page is showing contents...

Layout page

```
echo $this->Html->css('common');
echo $this->Html->css('dialog');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.min'); 
echo $this->Html->script('common');
```

.htaccess

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If you are using apache, have you tried enabling mod_rewrite in the apache settings file (httpd.conf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable mod_rewrite in your Apache config, you can find out more here, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

You can also turn this off the need for mod_rewrite if you need in the `app/config/core.php` line 84